# Sum of 3 numbers in same cell using a reference formula as well

Tags: excel, excel-formula

IN B1 I have: 3,4,5 
IN B2 I have the sum of these numbers 12

I would like to add these together and the sum to appear in B3

So, for B3, I need to tell excel to reference the cell holding the numbers, then add them together. This way, once I create the original formula, I can drag it through the remaining cells.

Reason is: The sum of these numbers (B2), are pulling the sum from a different location within the spreadsheet. I need to make sure these numbers match.

Thank you

Comment: Do you always have exactly three numbers separated by a coma in B1?

Answer (score 3):

Alternate solution (if exactly three numbers separated by a comma):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99*(ROW($1:$3)-1)+1,99))
```

Or, to make the formula more dynamic so that the B1 cell can have any quantity of numbers, as long as they are separated by a comma:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1))-1)+1,99))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have three numbers separated by a coma.

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)-1) + MID(B1,FIND(",",B1)+1,FIND(",",B1,FIND(",",B1)+1)-FIND(",",B1)-1) + MID(B1,FIND(",",B1,FIND(",",B1,FIND(",",B1)+1))+1,100)
```

If I break down the formula it's a bit simpler to see what is going on.

1st number:

```
LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)-1)
```

2nd number:

```
MID(B1,FIND(",",B1)+1,FIND(",",B1,FIND(",",B1)+1)-FIND(",",B1)-1)
```

3rd number:

```
MID(B1,FIND(",",B1,FIND(",",B1,FIND(",",B1)+1))+1,100)
```

Comment: I think you are right, can't test it but it seems so. I wrote that in here directly (only have excel for mac - which I hate - right now and in french so functions are different)