# How to sum values separated by semicolon in excel cell

Tags: excel

I have cell in excel that contains multiple values separated by semicolon, I need to sum each cell.

Number of values in each cell is N (unknown), it can be only one value or it can be 20 or more.

The issue why I have values separated by semicolon is that each row represents product that we are selling. In that row is cell that contains selling prices of that product.
Example
Product called "indoor door" were sold three times at different price, so cell contains three values: 102,5;98,2;101,00 Now I need to sum those three values to get total price (at which product was sold).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of 3 numbers in same cell using a reference formula as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20576632/1578604) with the exception that you have `;` here instead of `,`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of 3 numbers in same cell using a reference formula as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576105/sum-of-3-numbers-in-same-cell-using-a-reference-formula-as-well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following formula:

```
=eval(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ";", "+"),",","."))
```

after adding user defined function to your workbook:

```
Function eval(str As String)
   eval = Evaluate(str)
End Function
```

Comment: Just tried it and I get #Value! error. I've added your function to my workbook so this is not an issue. 
If any easier I've uploaded my test workbook or if you don't mind uploading your example with working function.
Link
[link to workbook](http://www.filedropper.com/book2_2)

Comment: Try to use `=eval(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ";", "+"))`. Is it works? It depends of your number format on PC (I mean it depends on the type of decimal separator on your PC - `,` or `.`). P.s. it works in my PC with your workbook

Comment: That's odd, I tried both methods. 
Here are my number settings of windows 8. 
[link screenshot of settings](http://s29.postimg.org/hp0p9n5hj/Capture.png)

Comment: do you have function `SUBSTITUTE` in your excel? it may be called differently because of language features.

Comment: I do have SUBSTITUTE function.

Comment: what does `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ";", "+"),",",".")` return for you?

Comment: Ok problem solved, I don't know if there is any difference between office versions but I had to use this formula (look at seperators in formula I had to use semicolons you used colons.
`=eval(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;";"; "+");",";"."))`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the **array formula** :

```
=SUM((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",REPT(" ",255)),1+(ROW(A1:A999)-1)*255,255)) & "0")/10)
```

Array formulas are entered with **CNTRL-SHFT-ENTER** rather than just the **ENTER**  key.

So if A1 contained:

1;2;3

the formula should return 6

Comment: check please, if it works for `10,2;10,3`..it returns `2,05` for me..

Comment: You are correct..........my formula only works with no commas...unless the comma is your **decimal separator**

Comment: Hi, I know this is 5 years down the track but I wanted to add that from Excel 2013 onwards, you can omit the `& "0" / 10` section for coercing blanks to 0s, and use `NUMBERVALUE()` instead. This also fixes the problem where your formula returns incorrect results with comma-separated period decimal values (e.g. 34.5 becomes 34.50 / 10 -> 3.45) The amended expression would be `=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",255)),1+(ROW(A1:A999)-1)*255,255))))`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `text to column` tab to separate numbers and put them in separate cells then you can use sum function on them.