# how to add comma separated numbers in excel column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I get the `desired_output` for a given input column containing comma-separated single numeric values as shown in the picture?

Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: Is there always one comma ?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? If yes, please show it otherwise this is just requesting to do the homework for you.

Comment: i just found a easy way to do it by simply converting the comma separated values into columns by using Data > Text to Columns feature. I now have columns for each number and can simply add them to get the desired outcome.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your comma-separated values in cell A1, the following array formula will add all such values:

```
=SUM((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",255)),1+(ROW(A1:A999)-1)*255,255)) & "0")/10)
```

To properly return the formula, you need to press `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER`, instead of just the usual `ENTER`.

Comment: Repeating comment from similar reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921561/how-to-sum-values-seperated-by-semicolon-in-excel-cell/20922166#comment99594908_20922166 From Excel 2013 onwards, you can omit the `& "0" / 10` section for coercing blanks to 0s, and use NUMBERVALUE() instead. This also fixes the problem where period decimal values return incorrect results (e.g. 34.5 -> 34.50 / 10 -> 3.45) The amended expression would be `=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",255)),1+(ROW(A1:A999)-1)*255,255))))`. Haven't tested with locales using comma decimal separators tho