# How can I sum numbers in the same line in power query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

Good Morning,

I have some doubt in PowerQuery, i have a column with some numbers in the same line that I need to sum, how can I do it?

Example input

```
field 1    |   field 2 | field 3
Planeacion    2,3,1     2,2,2


field 1   | field 2  | field 3
Planeacion   6           6
```

output

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: pulled from the interwebz: `=SUM(0+TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,(1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))))*99,99)))`

Comment: There is also a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20922166/6706419) doing the same thing but with semi-colons instead of commas. If you search the correct terms, chances are you will find the solution on your own :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In powerquery you can do this**

Click-select the columns with the commas

Right click, Replace values, and replace the comma with a plus ( , to +)

Click-select the same columns

Right click, Transform ... lowercase...

edit the resulting formula so that each time you see

```
Text.Lower, type text
```

you replace it with

```
each Expression.Evaluate(_), type number
```

Sample version for the two columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,",","+",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"field 2", "field 3"}),
#"Transform1"   = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"field 2", each Expression.Evaluate(_), type number}, {"field 3", each Expression.Evaluate(_), type number}})
in #"Transform1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[csv2list] 
(   
    @p1 varchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH List as (
    SELECT CAST (value AS varchar(max)) value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(@p1, 1, LEN(@p1)), ',') 
)
SELECT value
FROM List
)
GO
```

Then you can do:

SELECT * FROM csv2list('2,3,1');

which will produce:

```
2
3
1
```

or to sum them, use:

```
select sum(cast(value as integer)) from csv2list('2,3,1');
```