# Taking average of multiple numbers in a single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have a column called "ratings", with multiple values. A cell would look like this: 3, 4, 5
I want to take the average of these values and put it in another column. Is this possible?

The reason is that I dont want too many columns with a single value

Comment: Do you want to average just a single cell or a whole column of cells like that? What are the highest and lowest possible ratings?

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing tigeravatar's formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576632/1578604) and modifying it a little, you can use something like this, entered as array formula (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to use it after typing it, and not <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone):

```
=AVERAGE(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1))-1)+1,99))
```